# Is there a similar Se site that allows for general health questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I know that Biology.SE site is more about the science of biology and not about personal or general health, however, I was wondering if there was a site that you all tend to defer questioner's to if they have such unrelated questions.

In my case, I am curious.  I have been sick off-and-on throughout this season with various colds and I tend to drink a lot from bottled water.  My specific question is how long is too long to drink out of an opened bottle of water that I've drank from while sick?

In my case, I often find a bottle or two lying around the house that is a 1-2 days old and is 1/3 full.  If I'm well, I'll finish it off and not worry about it.  If I am or have been sick with a cold, I'm prone to toss the bottle.  In fact, I'll even toss it if I opened it in the morning and it's sat stagnant until the afternoon.

Is there a right place to ask such a question in Stack Exchange or is this an unanswerable question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>There is a health SE in area 51 that is currently in the commitment phase. Presently, it needs 68 more people to commit before it goes into to private beta.</s>

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66048/health

[Health.SE](http://health.stackexchange.com) is now in public beta.

Also, a medical Area 51 proposal was just closed. However, it can be restarted if you are interested and want to be the cheerleader for the proposal so it gets enough traffic, followers, and questions. Then maybe this time around it can make it to the commitment phase. Here is the old proposal.

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64668/medicine

Comment: Thank you, that is what I hoped to see.

Comment: @RLH are you going to become a committed person to health now or start medicine or both?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Just committed to Health.  I'm not looking to restart a proposal for something I'm not knowledgable enough to contribute answers to (Medicine.)

Comment: @RLH fair enough

Comment: Just to add, the SE has opened in beta phase.

Comment: @MarchHo I am aware I participate all private beta but requested my account be deleted.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is not about not knowing the answers. A medical advice has to be sought from a qualified practitioner and a public site like this does not ensure that.

There can be legal issues regarding this as well. I don't think there is any SE that would be suitable for this.

However there are other sites where qualified doctors provide advice. You can try them.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about drinking (also connected with health) could be also placed here:
[SE Beverages proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/105491/beverages?referrer=dvLAdylD4pnJeq7gt1oMpg2) if this site exists.

Also, [Cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/) and [Coffee](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/) have certain connections.